# Create a function dictionary

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I need a code in a function way, that contains a dictionary. The output have to be the dictionary value.
I wrote this one but it doesn't work. Can someone help me?

```
def a(paisos):
    d = {'España': 'la capiral es madrid', 'Francia': 'la capital es paris'}
    paisos = d.keys
    b = d.values
    if paisos in d:
        print(b)
    else:
        print('fail')
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets start from the beginning...

---

```
paisos = d.keys
b = d.values
```

what you wrote doesn't make sense, since `dict.values` and `dict.keys` are `method`s (we may say they are functions) and not `attribute`s, so you have to call them:

```
paisos = d.keys()
b = d.values()
```

---

```
if paisos in d:
```

What does it mean? `d` is an `object` of type `dict`, while `paisos` is a `list` (`return`ed by `d.keys()`)

---

If you want to get the `value` (the capital) from the `key` (the country) you have to do this:

```
def a(paisos):
    ...
    capital = d[paisos]
```

---

> [...] now the problem I have is that instead of printing fail when I write something that is not in the dictionary

No problem, you just have to use a `try`/`except` to handle a `KeyError` when the `key` doesn't exist in your `dict` (d):

```
try:
    capital = d[paisos]
except KeyError as error: # The country doesn't exist
    print("Something went wrong")
```

Comment: What I want to say is that, if I have 'España' or 'Francia' in the dictionary, print the d.value. I have just started in Python and I am not too good.

Comment: THANKS, now the problem I have is that instead of printing fail when I write something that is not in the dictionary, it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, you have to use a try/except block, I'll provide it in my answer so that it will be complete and you will be free to accept it